# Horizontal Scroll on UL

Tags: css, scroll

I'm trying to get a horizontal scroll bar on my series of unordered lists and can't for the life of me... I feel like I have the UL wrapped in a div with the right overflow settings.

```css
#pricing-table {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px; /* total computed width = 222 x 3 + 226 */*/
  height: 800px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#pricing-table .plan {
  font: 12px 'Lucida Sans', 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8);        
  background: #fff;      
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 250px; /* plan width = 180 + 20 + 20 + 1 + 1 = 222px */      
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.clear:before, .clear:after {
  content:"";
  display:table
}

.clear:after {
  clear:both
}
  
.clear {
  zoom:1
}
```

```html
<div id="pricing-table" class="clear">
  <div class="plan" id="most-popular">
<h3>Testing<span></span></h3>      
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>       
</ul> 
 </div>
<div class="plan">
<h3>Testing<span></span></h3>      
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>       
</ul> 
 </div>
   <div class="plan" id="most-popular">
<h3>Testing<span></span></h3>      
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>       
</ul> 
 </div>  
<div class="plan" id="most-popular">
<h3>Testing<span></span></h3>      
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>       
</ul> 
 </div>
  <div class="plan" id="most-popular">
<h3>Testing<span></span></h3>      
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>       
</ul> 
 </div>
 <div class="plan" id="most-popular">
<h3>Testing<span></span></h3>      
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>       
</ul> 
 </div>
</div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do you wants all `#plan` blocks in one row?

Comment: yes, just one row with a scroll bar

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar shows up, but it doesn't scroll.  The vertical scroll bar is hidden, so #plan blocks end up wrapping and stacking vertically until they go out of window.  If I change overflow-y to scroll from hidden, then I can scroll vertically.  Just need to figure out how to get the horizontal scroll instead of vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float` from child elements. Use `inline-block` instead and add `white-space: nowrap` on parent. It will prevent children from wrapping.

Following css will create horizontal scroll if needed.

```
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 800px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
#pricing-table {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; /* total computed width = 222 x 3 + 226 */*/
  height: 800px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#pricing-table .plan {
  font: 12px 'Lucida Sans', 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8);        
  background: #fff;      
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 250px; /* plan width = 180 + 20 + 20 + 1 + 1 = 222px */      
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}
.clear:before, .clear:after {
  content:"";
  display:table
}

.clear:after {
  clear:both
}

.clear {
  zoom:1
}
```

```html
<div id="pricing-table" class="clear">
  <div class="plan" id="most-popular">
    <h3>Testing<span></span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <h3>Testing<span></span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <h3>Testing<span></span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <h3>Testing<span></span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <h3>Testing<span></span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="plan">
    <h3>Testing<span></span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that worked!  3 hours of trying, you nailed it so quick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: flex` to id `#pricing-table`, and a `min-width: 250px` to class `.plan`

Check you updated CSS block:

```
#pricing-table {
margin: 100px auto;
text-align: center;
width: 800px; /* total computed width = 222 x 3 + 226 */*/
height: 800px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
display: flex;
}

#pricing-table .plan {
font: 12px 'Lucida Sans', 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8);        
background: #fff;      
border: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #333;
padding: 20px;
min-width: 250px; /* plan width = 180 + 20 + 20 + 1 + 1 = 222px */      
float: left;
position: relative;
}
.clear:before, .clear:after {
  content:"";
  display:table
}

.clear:after {
 clear:both
}

 .clear {
    zoom:1
   }
```